# Accessing data from heavily nested dynamic json object

Tags: node.js, json, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, object-destructuring

I have this response coming from Profit and Loss Report of Quickbooks, how to deal with this data effectively for calculations, can someone help me out?

Sample JSON response -> https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/721312385956315173/1146315707156545576/Screenshot_2023-08-29_204026.png

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/721312385956315173/1146328040939474954/Screenshot_2023-08-29_201259.png

Thank you for any help from your side!

I was trying to visualize the data at Online JSON Viewer, and then my mind boggled how to process the data.